# create a table with table and database statistics

Tags: sql-server, audit

There are around 200+ tables in our SQL DB and every table has 1 common field [updated_timestamp]

Is there a way to query the DB itself and list all tables, with the MAX value of [updated_timestamp] and the row count of each table?

i'm sorry if i've not explained that the best

are there secret/system tables that hold such info?

my desired output would be

| table | updated_timestamp | row_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Table A | 2022-08-22 | 89,854 |
| Table B | 2022-08-18 | 103,55,166 |

if there is a table like this i could intergate that would be great, but i'm assuming not that simple.

i picked up some code from another stored procedure and was hoping this would be of use for the row count at least

```
SELECT
      QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id)) AS [DB_Schema],
      QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) AS [TableName],
      SUM(sPTN.Rows) AS [Row_Count]
INTO ##tmpRowCount2
FROM 
      sys.objects AS sOBJ
      INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS sPTN
            ON sOBJ.object_id = sPTN.object_id
WHERE
      sOBJ.type = 'U'
      AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
      AND index_id < 2
GROUP BY 
      sOBJ.schema_id
      , sOBJ.name
ORDER BY [Row_Count]
GO

ALTER TABLE ##tmpRowCount2 ADD updated_timestamp datetime NULL;

-- keep only API rows
DELETE FROM ##tmpRowCount2
WHERE [DB_Schema] != '[api]'


DECLARE @Row_Count int
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @TableName as VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @DB_Schema as VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @updated_timestamp as DATETIME
DECLARE tablenamefromcursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT  TableName, 
        Row_Count, 
        DB_Schema
FROM ##tmpRowCount2
        
OPEN tablenamefromcursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tablenamefromcursor INTO  @TableName, @Row_Count, @DB_Schema
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'UPDATE ##tmpRowCount2  SET updated_timestamp = ' + 
            '(SELECT MAX([updated_timestamp]) FROM ' + @DB_Schema + '.' + @TableName + 
            ') WHERE TableName = ''' + @TableName + ''''
        
        EXEC(@sql)
        FETCH NEXT FROM tablenamefromcursor INTO  @TableName, @Row_Count, @DB_Schema
    END

CLOSE tablenamefromcursor
DEALLOCATE tablenamefromcursor
```

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL to get the values of the `MAX` `updated_timestamp` for *every* table. Also, are you storing delimited data in your column `row_count`? *Don't*.

Comment: @larnu I've attempted to use dynamic SQL but this is something i've never done before.  I want to use the table name in my temp table as variable so i can pass it to the cursor and perform the `SELECT MAX(updated_timestamp) from @tablenamefromcursor`

Answer (score 0):

Code editied above and i can confirm it works, by debugging with `select @sql` iwas able to parse the statement and edit the syntax unitl it worked by getting the parethesis and quotes in the right order

[image: select debugging]

Comment: Please honor the question and answer format of Stack Overflow. The question should maintain the original, problem code. The answer should include the corrected code.